# breaking up a char array into a structure

Tags: c, memcpy

In case someone gets this issue in the future I'll leave this up.

*Note This approach wasn't going to work when going from C client to C server. This would have only worked with the Java client to C server. So I had to abandoned this approach.

Ok, I've been fighting with C for too long now. I'm passing some info with UDP from a java client to a C server. I can get the info there, but I'm not sure how to break apart the message to store into a struct like so

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) clientMessage
{
  short tml; 
  short rid;  
  char op;        
  char message[MAXBUFLEN-5];
};
```

I recieve the message like this
Where test is a `char test[MAXBUFLEN-5];`

```
if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, test, MAXBUFLEN-1, 0,
  (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
     perror("recvfrom");
     exit(1);}
```

So, I need to take the message "7 2 1Yo" (two 2 byte shorts and a char followed by an unknown message length) and store it into it's appropriate parts in the struct. The message gets sent correctly, I just can't break it into the bits of info that I need. I'm currently attempting

```
memcpy(&cm.rid, &test, 2);
memcpy(&cm.tml, &test[1], 2);
memcpy(&cm.op, &test[4], 1);
memcpy(&cm.message, &test[5], MAXBUFLEN-5);
```

But my resutls end up being

```
Message: Yo
OP: 1Yo
RID: 7 1Yo
TML: 2 7 1Yo
```

it Should be

```
Message: Yo
OP: 1
RID: 2
TML: 7
```

I successfully get the message, but nothing else. I'm relatively new to C so forgive my ignorance. I'm guessing this is really easy but idk.

Comment: By `//empty`, do you mean `0`? Why isn't it `char test[MAXBUFLEN]`? Why do the contents of `test` invert the order of `rid` and `tml` in your structure? You are passing a pointer to an array to `memcpy()` as a source address (you won't notice a difference if `test` is an array, but it is of the wrong type). You can fix by removing the `&` , if what you meant was `&test[0]`. Shouldn't it be `memcpy(&cm.tml, &test[2], 2);`?

Comment: Have you considered endianness issues? Also, if `rid` and `tml` are both two bytes, why are you memcpy-ing into `tml` from `&test[1]`?

Comment: I'd also suggest ordering your struct members to match the order they appear in the network stream, for sanity's sake.

Comment: What are you trying to print? Shouldn't it either be 4 hexadecimal digits, or a 5 digit decimal (that may be negative)? I still don't understand what empty means.

Comment: Forget that it's empty for now. The message that I'm sending "7 2 1Yo" Is printing out fine when I print out the whole char "test". When attempting to pull out the bits of info I need from that char, I get weird results.

Comment: Yea, it's just a test string but all subsequent strings will be the same (with different messages, but first 3 values will be of a similar format). It's incoming from a UDP packet sent by a Java client. @jxh

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be `memcpy(&cm.rid, &test[0], 2);`, for the address is supposed to be the address of the first byte.

And the rest:

```
memcpy(&cm.tml, &test[2], 2); // you want to get the third and forth byte, begin with index 2.
memcpy(&cm.op, &test[4], 1);  // the fifth byte, begin with index 4.
memcpy(&cm.message, &test[5], MAXBUFLEN-5); // the rest bytes.
```

Comment: test,  and &test[0] are the same thing

Comment: @ScottyBauer Yes, I just want to keep in accordance with the author's code.

Comment: I updated my question. I cleaned up my code to match this better. I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @ChaunceyPhilpot Your code is not changed as what you said. Endian is another question, which need more details. But I do not think your question is involved with byte order.

Answer (score 0):

Since `test` contains the string `"7 2 1Yo"`, you have to parse the string into the values you want. You can do this with `sscanf()`:

```
char fmt[256];
snprintf(fmt, sizeof(fmt), "%%hd %%hd %%c%%%ds", MAXBUFLEN-5-1);
sscanf(test, fmt, &cm.rid, &cm.tml, &cm.op, cm.message);
```

In this code fragment above, we create a format string for the parsing. This is necessary to prevent `sscanf()` from scanning past the end of the message in the case that it is not `\0` terminated. The result of the `snprintf()` call with a `MAXBUFLEN` of 128 is:

```
"%hd %hd %c%122s"
```

Which tells `sscanf()` to scan for two short decimal numbers, a `char`, and a string no longer than 122 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a binary protocol, it would be better to use e.g. `int16_t` instead of short in the declaration of `clientMessage` because the size of short is not specified within the c standard.

To access the message stored in `test` you could do simply something like this:

```
struct clientMessage *cm = (struct clientMessage *) test;
```

You should also notice, that the endianness of network protocols is different from the endianness of a x86 and amd64 architecture, so instead of 42 you might recieve 10752.
To fix this you can use the `ntohs()` (Network TO Host Short) function to acces the `tm` and `rid`.

Comment: `sizeof(short)` is not specified in C but its _minimum_ range is specified to be at _least_ -32767 to 32767, thus `short` can store all integers that `int16_t` can with the lone potential exception of -32768.  In any case, I too prefer `int16_t` over `short`.

Comment: @chux: The point is that you don't want it to be bigger. If the other end of the connection is expecting two bytes, you don't want to accidentally send it four just because the implementation on this side of the connection exceeds the minimum and has a 32 bit short.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths  My concern with Ruge Bolek post was stating "size of short is not specified", though true, is misleading as there are limits as to what a short can be.  OP's issue is messaging between a Java short and a C _something_.  The C type `int16_t`, where available, matches the Java short, thus making it the preferred type.  Should `int16_t` not be available, the receiving end may need to resort to bigger types and of course on sending should qualifies its values.

Answer (score 0):

Use **sscanf()** for the first part and **memcpy()** for the text.

```
const char *message = "7 2 1Yo";
struct clientMessag cM;  
int offset = 0;
int n;
n = sscanf(message, "%hd %hd %c%n", &cM.tml, &cM.rid, &cM.op, &offset);
size_t SuffixLength = strlen(&message[offset]);
if ((n != 3) || (SuffixLength >= sizeof(cM.message))) {
  exit(1);  // handle syntax error;
}
memcpy(cM.message, &message[offset], SuffixLength + 1);
// Additional field checks like IsOKOpCode(cM.op)
```

I avoided `%s` as it does not store whitespace into your message.
Error checking is always good to do.  Recommend additional field checks.

---

BTW: its not clear if the `cM.op` field should be treat as text or a number.  Does the OP want a 1 or '1' stored?  The above assume text.  Alternatively one could use `"%hd%hd%hhd%n"`.